# Install HAXM on OS X Yosemite for make android simulator working

Tags: android, android-studio, osx-yosemite, haxm, kernel-extension

I need to use the AndroidStudio simulator, but the IDE show me follow error:

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX is not installed on this machine (/dev/HAX is missing).

So I tried to find in the web solutions to solve my problem; finally I tried this:

1) I went to AndroidStudio > tools > android > SDK android and I installed HAXM

[image]

2) then I went to android > sdk > extras > intel, I opened Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager directory and start installing IntelHAXM_1.1.4.dmg; at the end the wizard showed me this error

[image]

3) surfing the web I found some guides for to force to install the kext (this I intended) and I tried to write tis on terminal

[image]

Restarting the system, the simulator does not work. could anyone help me solve my problem? installing the HAXM, or deactivate it, both are fine.
Thanks a lot!!!

EDIT: finaly I solved this problem simply change the SDK from 6.0 to 5.1.1, so the emulator didn't bind me to use HAXM; however if someone has some solution, please write evenly.

Comment: Just as a sanity check - do you have Parallels or VMWare installed on your Mac?

Comment: No, I don't... so I noticed that I was using sdks 6.0 marshmallow, it could be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at your second screenshot the title of the message reads: 
**VT/NX not enabled**

Intel installation instructions (see:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x) claim:

> Note: Apple* computers have Intel VT-x permanently enabled if supported by the processor.
>   If you receive an error message indicating that Intel VT is not enabled, your computer does not meet the minimum system requirements to use Intel HAXM. To determine the capabilities of your Intel processor, visit http://ark.intel.com/.

Probably the CPU of your computer doesn't support VT-x. I suggest you try the link cited above to make sure your CPU supports VT-x. In case it is, it may be disabled in BIOS / EFI, next step would be to take a look there.

VT-x is a required feature for HAXM to work. No VT-x no HAXM.

Comment: Probably it's disabled in BIOS because I think that an i7 3.8 ghz could support VT-x! I'll take a look tomorrow, tanks for the suggest.

Comment: Here is what apple writes: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203296 maybe you are just missing an update.

Comment: so at this point there is an other problem: I use both a MacBook Pro and an Hackintosh like a MacPro: I assembled this Hackintosh one year ago, so components would not be early 2008 (late MacPro i think). However I don't know if installing this BIOS update would make my PC not working. I'll try to update BIOS in the MacBook Pro.

Comment: Have you checked virtualization isn't disabled in BIOS? It is usually disabled on non genuine apple machines. `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features` should contain `VMX` if the CPU supports VT-x, even if it is disabled in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify if it is a signature problem (even if it sounds a bit strange) anyway:

```
sudo kextutil -bunlde-id com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
```

If the signature problem is your problem, then:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"
```

and restart. Re-install HAXM.

You can give a look [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/09/haxm-module-problem-in-os-x-yosemite-fix.html), this is my blog post about it.

Comment: Using the first command terminal show me com.intel.kext.intelhaxm not of type 'kext'.
usage: kextutil [options] [--] [kext] ...
I try for the next time to use sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1" and restart, reinstalling HAXM. I just gave a look to your post and I just tried to solve with your "trick": if I have other problem can i contact you by chat?

Comment: I restart but it does not work; it shows the same windows as the image two. do you know how to uninstall HAXM and use the emulator evenly?

Comment: It seems you disabled some features (like virtualisation) even if i have doubt. Check this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/how-to-turn-on-intel-vt-in-macbook-pro-2011-mc721ll-a to know if it is true

Comment: So how can i know where that windows is? How can I find Intel settings on my Mac?